# Guest OS booting hangs in virtualbox

Tags: boot, virtualbox, virtualhost

I am running virtualbox 4.3.10 in ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have a working guest OS of open suse 13.1 in this virtualbox.

**What I have done**

I exported this appliance to `ova` file, so that I can use it in another system by importing the `ova` file. After the successful export to get the file `filename.ova`, I imported this file in virtualbox.The import was successful and this created another entry for the guest OS in virtualbox menu.

I thought after the successful import, the new guest OS will exactly run same as the old guest OS.

**What happened**

The boot screen comes ok, but the **booting is not getting completed**.
It doesn't shows any error message also.

**I have also tried**

I have also tried copying the .vdi file for working guest OS and adding to virtualbox(in another system with windows host). There also the **boot starts and hangs**.

How to make it OK?

Comment: Same here, unable to find where the hell is the problem.